# TFS cannot rollback: "The item being rolled back has changed in a later version"

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, merge, rollback

**The Scenario**

### I want to rollback a changeset.

**The Problem**

When I perform **Rollback Entire Changeset** from my **$/SAM/Main** branch using the VS2012 IDE, the **Resolve Conflicts** tab displays, and *ALL of the files I'm trying to rollback* have the following message associated with them:

```
The item being rolled back has changed in a later version
Changes being rolled back: 54460~54460 Your workspace version is: 54460
You have a pending change on the item
```

At this point, the only option available to me in the **Resolve Conflicts** tab is an **Undo Rollback** button.

---

**Things to Note**

- CS54460 was created using the following command line:

  **merge $/SAM/Dev $/SAM/Main /discard /recursive /version:C54426~C54426**
- CS54460, when viewing the **Changeset Details**, performs a **[merge, branch, delete]** on ALL the files.

---

**Why I Need to Do This**

I need to do this, because I need to merge **CS54426** from the **$/SAM/Dev** branch up to the **$/SAM/Main** branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by using the following command:

```
merge $/SAM/Dev $/SAM/Main /recursive **/force** /version:C54426~C54426
```

This forced the changeset I needed in $/SAM/Dev to disregard the "Keep Yours" changeset in $/SAM/Main, thus merging the code I needed up to the $/SAM/Main branch.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use rollback,  just do it manually:

- get the version you want to roll back to
- back up the changed files
- check out the changed files. If you're lucky the old code will be preserved but the checkout may force you back to the newest  version.
- so if necessary copy the backups over the master source files again
- test and check in

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the error "TF203051: Cannot rollback item *XYZ* because the workspace version of the item is at or older than the version to which you are trying to rollback to. Update the version in your workspace to a newer version than the version to which you are trying to rollback to and then retry your operation." when attempting to roll back to a specific version in the history in VS2017.
The problem was that file *XYZ*, one of the files was included in multiple changesets, a second one was more recent than the one I was trying to roll back.
Luckily I needed to roll back that too. So the solution was to roll back both versions at the same time by selecting them together in the history view of Source Control Explorer.